# How do I handle/confront an employee who is cheating in an Office competition?

Tags: management, people-management, privacy, competition, bathroom

I was recently promoted to a middle management position at my office where I have about a half floor of employees working under me.

As part of a company health initiative, I decided to co-host a month-long competition amongst the 6 teams on my (and my co-host's) floor to encourage them to drink more water.
In the break room on our floor we have a different watercooler per each team and we are keeping track of which team is drinking the most water for the month (by counting water jug replacements).
The winning team receives a paid dinner at a very expensive resteraunt that is an office favorite.

My office is just outside of the breakroom so I'm able to hear if there are any water dumping/adding shenanigans going on which I luckily have not had to shut down.

The competition was going smooth for the first week until I noticed one employee who had been excessively refilling his water bottle from his team's cooler.
We will call him Kurt.

At first, I thought maybe Kurt was just thirsty from exercise or had a salty lunch but his consistency was concerning. I started to count how often Kurt refilled his 32oz
bottle and in one day he seemed to have drank over a gallon and a half of water within our 7 hour 30 minute workday??

Kurt's team pulled a massive lead in just a few days which gives me reason to believe that Kurt's behavior is intentional as for the first week his team was consistent with the office.

I began taking note of Kurt's restroom habits as well just to be sure he wasn't taking his water with him. Sure enough, he's been going to the restroom nearly twice an hour,
but did not take his water bottle so I lost any suspicion of deliberate cheating.

I chalked it up to impressive dedication until this morning when I saw a syringe on Kurt's desk. I inquired what that was for, as it seemed out of place, he mentioned he has to take insulin for his Diabetes. I apologized for the invasive question and went to my office which is where it all clicked.

I'm certain Kurt has been intentionally reducing his insulin intake in order to drink/expend more water. My nephew developed adolescent diabetes a few years ago and apparently.
one of the tell-tale signs of it was excessive urination as his Kidneys were working overtime to clear out glucose as he couldn't produce insulin.

I'm at a loss on what to do. On one hand, I admire Kurt's dedication to getting his team that dinner, on the other hand, Kurt's Armstrongesque behavior is of concern to my own ethics.
It would feel wrong to reward Kurt and his team when they've had an extreme advantage over all of the other teams.

Additionally, I do not know how to confront this as some may think I've been invasive into Kurt's personal life giving my logging of his water intake/outtake and discovering his diabetic condition. However, this is all due to my diligent effort to make this office competition fair for all.

I'm not sure if I should cancel the competition, confront Kurt in private, bring my findings to my co-host, or take this directly to HR. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Drinking too much water can kill you and is definitively not healthy. Don't force yourself to drink water. People sometimes forget to drink enough water in stressful environments but we're talking about moderate amounts. And your body is usually very good at signaling if it had enough or needs more water. More people die at marathons because of over excessive water consumption, then from dehydration.

Comment: @seg This is obvious. The competition is supposed to encourage employees choosing water over less healthy alternatives. This is part of my frustration with Kurt's behavior.

Comment: Water intoxication can lead to death. And why isn't it your concern that one of your coworkers is literally forgoing their medication. This whole thing is apparently about employee health but that doesn't appear to be your concern.

Comment: This is so outrageously wrong I'm voting to close it as a troll post.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins I thought it might be a troll post too but I think the general question "how can I encourage employees to do something for their health" is still useful.

Comment: The timing is especially sus as it was posted as most of Reddit- a site famous for creative writing exercises masquerading as real life- was shut down.

Comment: I don't mean to be dismissive but, don't you guys have real work to do?

Comment: Why wold the guy risk kidney impairment or dead? who says he is not skipping the "middleman" and just using the syringe to take the bottle water to the toilets?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Honestly, I’d shut the whole thing down “after re-evaluation” (but don’t mention anything about Kurt or sportsmanship - just come up with a plausible cover story), and make the dinner a “pick a name out of a hat” prize instead so staff don’t lose out.

It might be a bit of an uncomfortable climb-down but it’ll be easier than trying to fix what you’ve got at the moment.

As well-intentioned as it might have been, you’ve not introduced a health drive - you’ve created a competitive office-based game-show where teams of contestants have to drink as much water as possible within a time limit to win a prize, to the point where you have unintended consequences of people messing with their prescribed medication to get an advantage.

And you’re also spending work time monitoring toilet breaks to police it!

Drinking water is *part* of a healthy lifestyle but you’ve gamified it into a single point-scoring objective, and drinking *excessive* water can even be harmful:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_intoxication

> Water intoxication, also known as water poisoning, hyperhydration, overhydration, or water toxemia, is a **potentially fatal** disturbance in brain functions that results when the normal balance of electrolytes in the body is pushed outside safe limits by excessive water intake.

Here’s a very famous case of it happening in the UK within a 90 minute window…

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_Leah_Betts

> A subsequent inquest determined that her death was not directly caused by the consumption of ecstasy, but rather the result of the large quantity of water she had consumed. She had apparently been in observation of an advisory warning commonly given to ravers which stated drinking water would help her avoid dehydration as a result of continuous dancing.

Maybe that’s a more complicated (and tragic) story than yours, but do you *really* want to be encouraging your staff to drink as much water as possible?

It’s great that you’re thoughtful enough to want to invest in improving the health and well-being of your workforce, but if you decide to run a similar initiative in future, maybe get some guidance from a health professional first :-).

Comment: Just adding: if you’re really invested in having your colleagues make the healthy beverage choices, limit the unhealthy ones and provide more of the alternatives.

Comment: Thank you Mclayton, I appreciate your insight to my issue. I think I'll go ahead and shut down the competition. When I posed it to my co-host we never thought people would be doing anything dangerous, just getting a glass of water as opposed to a coffee, soda or tea in the break room! Not anything like withholding medications to consume more!

Comment: Well, you could still make that a *personal* challenge for people to substitute less healthy drinks for water instead, just with no measuring achievement, and with the “prize” being an improved lifestyle - just disconnect desirable and valuable dinner as a motivator to take the pressure off participants need to “compete” in the challenge, and offer it to a *randomly* selected person instead. That might be a good way to spin it to your teams - “we’ve decided to drop the competitive aspect and will be awarding the prize to a random team member - please email abc@xyz to enter the draw”…

Answer (score 10):

**If you create stupid incentives, people will behave stupidly.**

You asked your people to drink more water, so they go out of their way to drink more water. You did NOT ask them to eat or drink healthier, you did NOT ask them to drink less soda or eat less salt, you did NOT ask them to better control their calorie intake and exercise more.

You asked them drink more water and that's what they do.

> How do I handle/confront an employee who is cheating in an Office competition?

How is he cheating? What rules is he violating ?

> on the other hand, Kurt's Armstrongesque behavior is of concern to my own ethics

It better be. After all it's YOUR contest that created an incentive for him to compromise his health.

> I'm not sure if I should cancel the competition,

Yes, you should. Its not working.

> confront Kurt in private,

What about? After all he is just doing what you wanted him to do.

> or take this directly to HR.

Not a great idea. As far as I can tell Kurt has not violated any company policy or contest rules. You, on the other hand, are trying to control what your employees eat or drink, define what healthy behaviors are, and incentivize an employee to jeopardize their health for a cool dinner. HR may frown on this.

> Any advice is appreciated.

Look, I understand that you meant well. This was well intended put poorly conceived and executed. You set rules that encouraged behavior that you didn't anticipate and that is  contrary to your goals. But that's still your fault not the people's who play by the rules that you created.

Best you can do is to admit your mistake and backpaddle. Cancel the contest, apologize (if you can find it in your heart to do so), and make sure everyone wins, even if you have to shell out more money.

That's not easy, but good leaders CAN admit they were wrong and take action to remedy what was done.

Comment: I wonder how dumb one must be to participate in such a stupid competition?

Answer (score 4):

Usual rule: if you don't want people to do silly things, don't encourage them to do so. Find a different way to encourage people to drink more water.

Comment: But it's not the competition's fault or the creator of it that those people are willing to take part in it.

Answer (score 2):

If your objective is to inspire people to adopt healthier habits, particularly reducing sugar intake, tracking water consumption is not a good idea.

Addressing such sensitive and private matters requires the implementation of an honor system rather than fostering competition among individuals. It's crucial to recognize that people have diverse needs and abilities.

Here's my suggested approach:

Allow each employee to set their own wellness goals. While you can suggest objectives such as reducing soda consumption by 50%, they might have other ideas in mind. For instance, they might aim to use a standing desk for at least two hours a day or decrease their smoking habits. Ensure that whatever goal they choose is quantifiable. However, there shouldn't be any compulsion for them to disclose their goal. They can choose to share it with you or their colleagues if they wish, but it's not a requirement.

Next, have them maintain a private log of their actions to monitor their progress towards achieving their chosen goal. This log should remain confidential and only serve as a self-monitoring tool. At the end of each week, individuals should report whether they have met their weekly target. You could display the collective results on a scoreboard in the office, turning this into a small weekly event.

After a predetermined period, such as three months, celebrate everyone who achieved their goals at least 80% of the time. More often than not, this will include everybody of your team. The celebration doesn't have to be an extravagant dinner at an expensive restaurant; it could be a modest but enjoyable gathering at a more affordable venue if budget is a concern.

This approach demonstrates trust in your employees, encourages them to compete with themselves instead of others, and promotes a healthier lifestyle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are damned if you do, damned if you don't.

Kurt has stuck to the letter of the law in regards to the competition, maybe not the spirit of the competition - but that's a different question.

As an F1 fan - Kurt is doing what teams have been doing since the inception of competitive sports - finding an advantage and leveraging it.

Now - is Kurt cheating? You could make an argument that he is, however I would counter that he is no more cheating than anyone else who has a biological advantage in a certain field. He is also assuming the risk of doing so - if his plan back-fires, he's going to be the one on a trip to the ER.

If he is, in fact, drinking the water (not squeezing it into plant pots or squeezing it down the toilet) - then you are going to have to accept that you got out-smarted and his team is going to win.

In terms of where you went wrong - you had a competition with no upper-limit. Rather than encouraging people to drink a healthy amount of water, you've encouraged drinking the most you possibly can.

With the competition - since it has been going on for a while - if you change the rules or declare it invalid, it will be seen poorly. If you 'expose' the advantage that Kurt has, you may be breaching privacy laws and it will create a toxic work environment.

If there is such a clear advantage by Kurt's team - you could maybe call it early and then later have a private chat with Kurt that you suspect he used a medical condition to give himself a competitive advantage. You could say that **if** that were true, you would be disappointed as you feel it's against the spirit of the competition. Leave it at that - nothing formal, no follow-up.

*Then next time you come up with an Office Comp - think a little bit harder about the rules so that you don't have a similar issue*